# Is there any Boosting algorithm with closed-form solutions?

Tags: machine-learning

My goal is to formulate the learning and generalization phases of any [Boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) algorithm as a matrix-vector operation.

Through Google, I found a good pdf (*) describing several boosting algorithms but the author Marco Cusumano-Towner only hints and doesn't explain how to recast the boosting algorithms (GradientBoost, Adaboost, QuadBoost) using matrix operations.

My question is:

Can I formulate a boosting algorithm as a regression, a game or a linear programming and arrive at closed-form solution which uses only matrix operations?

(*) [Boosting with log-loss](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1b3f/cf95f1f5450aa676bd6935851dd8dc121afd.pdf)

Comment: This seems pretty broad, and I don't know of any reason to expect there to be a simple universal solution.  Boosting is a generic method that can be applied to many different kinds of weak learners.  I suspect everything will depend on the specifics of the weak learners you use with boosting, and I don't know of any reason to expect that the solution will necessarily be matrix-vector operations or to expect the same answer for all weak learners.

Comment: Also, AdaBoost as normally described doesn't involve computation of any gradients (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost#Example_algorithm_(Discrete_AdaBoost)), so I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "to avoid iterative computing of gradients", and I'm not sure why expressing it in matrix-vector operations would be any better than the standard way it is expressed.

Comment: Since you mention gradients, are you familiar with [gradient boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) and [xgboost](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754)?  Xgboost deals with the special case where the weak learner is a decision tree algorithm, and might be related to what you're hoping for.  Apologies if I'm telling you things you already know and are familiar with.

Comment: nice comments D.W.. I simplified and edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Basically: no.  Boosting is a "meta-method".  If you have a weak learner (an algorithm for learning), it is a way of taking advantage of that weak learner algorithm iteratively to do better at learning some concept than the weak learner would do on its own.

Many/most weak learners don't have a closed-form solution for the model they build; instead, their learning algorithm may fundamentally rely upon iterative methods, optimization algorithms, or other techniques.  As a result, boosting with such a weak learner won't have a closed-form solution, either.